# Is it possible to see full history for file if it was merged from branch to trunk?

Tags: svn

Is it possible to see full history for file if it was merged from branch to trunk?
Or only history for trank will be accessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `svn log --use-merge-history` if you're referring to versions of svn that truly understand merging (1.5 and later).

Comment: Is it possible to do it in TortoiseSVN?

Comment: Check the "Include merged revisions" box.